# Seeking Appropriate Mixed Effects Model for Covariance Structure in Grouped, Repeated Measures Data

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, panel-data, covariance

I'm currently working on a project where I need to identify an appropriate model that accurately fits the data generation process of my study. The goal is to have a model in which the covariance matrix aligns with the structure of the `var_cor` matrix utilized in the data generation process, i.e. a block diagonal matrix.

My experimental design involves both a between-subject factor, `group`, and a repeated measure, `timepoint`. Subjects have been randomly assigned to groups, so I do not anticipate correlations between groups. However, I do expect to see correlations across timepoints within the same group. Additionally, there is an observed heterogeneous variance across both groups and timepoints, so the models needs to be heteroskedastic.

I've attempted various modeling approaches, but none have managed to successfully reflect the data's covariance structure. Here are the specifics of my data generation and the modeling attempts:

### Data Generation

I generated my data using the following code:

```r
# Libraries
library(MASS)
library(data.table)

# Parameters
n <- 5 # per group
n_groups <- 2
n_timepoints <- 2

# Seed
set.seed(123)

# Mean values for 3 groups and 3 timepoints
mean_vector <- 1:(n_groups * n_timepoints)

# Generate positive-definite covariance matrices for a single group
generate_cov_matrix <- function() {
  A <- matrix(rnorm(n_timepoints^2), ncol = n_timepoints)
  t(A) %*% A
}

cov_matrices <- replicate(n_groups, generate_cov_matrix(), simplify = FALSE)

# Create a block diagonal covariance matrix
cov_matrix <- bdiag(cov_matrices)

# Generate data using mvrnorm
response <- mvrnorm(n, mu = mean_vector, Sigma = cov_matrix)

# Transform into a data.table
DT <- data.table(group = paste0('G', rep(1:n_groups, each = n * n_timepoints)),
                 timepoint = rep(paste0('T', rep(1:n_timepoints, each = n)), n_groups),
                 response = c(response))
DT[, subject := paste0(paste0('S', rep(1:n, n_timepoints)), group)]
```

### Data

```r
> DT
    group timepoint   response subject
 1:    G1        T1  0.8047584    S1G1
 2:    G1        T1  1.2090650    S2G1
 3:    G1        T1 -0.3374251    S3G1
 4:    G1        T1  0.8627816    S4G1
 5:    G1        T1  2.1653801    S5G1
 6:    G1        T2  2.1238454    S1G1
 7:    G1        T2  1.0917584    S2G1
 8:    G1        T2  4.6728855    S3G1
 9:    G1        T2  2.8320545    S4G1
10:    G1        T2 -1.0554568    S5G1
11:    G2        T1  4.3566850    S1G2
12:    G2        T1  3.6287752    S2G2
13:    G2        T1  0.6315310    S3G2
14:    G2        T1  2.3297947    S4G2
15:    G2        T1  2.0412078    S5G2
16:    G2        T2  3.3564104    S1G2
17:    G2        T2  3.2535482    S2G2
18:    G2        T2  5.2115228    S3G2
19:    G2        T2  4.3901145    S4G2
20:    G2        T2  4.1569269    S5G2
```

### Modeling Attempts

Here are the models I've tried to fit:

1. Using `lme4`:

```r
library(lme4)

mdl_lmer <- lmer(formula = response ~ group * timepoint + (1 | timepoint) + (0 + group:timepoint | subject),
                 data = DT)

VarCorr(mdl_lmer)
```

2. Using `lme4qtl`:

```r
library(lme4qtl)
library(Matrix)

# Build a block diagonal relatedness matrix for the random effect
relmat <- kronecker(diag(n_groups), matrix(1, n_timepoints, n_timepoints))

# Fit model
mdl_qtl <- relmatLmer(formula = response ~ group * timepoint + (1 | timepoint) + (0 + group:timepoint | subject),
                      relmat = list(group = relmat),
                      data = DT)

VarCorr(mdl_qtl)
```

3. Using `nlme`:

```r
library(nlme)
mdl_lme <- lme(response ~ group * timepoint,
               random = ~ 1 | subject,
               correlation = corAR1(),
               data = DT)

VarCorr(mdl_lme)

mdl_lme_2 <- lme(response ~ group * timepoint, 
                 random = ~ 1 | group/subject, 
                 weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | group:timepoint), 
                 data = DT)

VarCorr(mdl_lme_2)
```

Comment: We have 20 data points and some of these models straight-up try to estimate more coefficients that (e.g. the `lme4` one). Yeah, any estimates will be horrible. *Massively* increase the sample size and then try again. There are a lot of heuristics about minimum size for regression analysis but even the most optimistic ones aren't below 7-8 sample per coefficient/independent variable.

Comment: @usεr11852 the data points are not the issue here, as this is just an example and we could increase the data points to 1000 if we wish so. My focus is on estimating the correct model. In this case I used very few data points so I could print the data in this post.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help with the problem but I was just wondering where would the variance for the random effect of timepoint (e.g. in lmer model) come from? I've been under the impression that a fixed effect of a categorical predictor captures exactly the same variance as the random effect of that predictor so I was just wondering are there some circumstances in which you can enter both into the model and if so, where does the "extra" variance come from?

Comment: I don't think any of these work, because the data generating process is very unstructured. You have massive heteroscedacity because the diagonal values aren't constant and changing correlation matrices depending on the group, which does not seem to be implemented in any of the packages. Also you don't use that you are dealing with time points at all. Maybe check out this and rethink the data-generation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlme/versions/3.1-152/topics/corClasses